# Scipy: Bessel iterative filtering different than single shot filtering

Tags: python, scipy, filtering

I have this piece of code that applies a Bessel filter:

**One-shot version:**

```
import scipy.signal

fc_bessel = 0.14  # [Hz]
ordre_bessel = 3

b,a = scipy.signal.bessel(ordre_bessel, fc_bessel, 'low', analog=False, output='ba', fs=300)

filter_once = scipy.signal.lfilter(b, a, input_data)
```

As I will in the end receive my data in real-time, I need to adapt this code to take each `input_data` on the fly, so I need to maintain the filter state in a `zi` variable. So I wrote:

**Iterative version:**

```
import scipy.signal

fc_bessel = 0.14  # [Hz]
ordre_bessel = 3

b,a = scipy.signal.bessel(ordre_bessel, fc_bessel, 'low', analog=False, output='ba', fs=300)
z = scipy.signal.lfilter_zi(b, a)

filter_iter = []
for input_value in input_data:
    filtered_value, z = scipy.signal.lfilter(b, a, [input_value], zi=z)
    filter_iter.append(filtered_value[0])
```

However, the outputs are completly different (if first value is a 0, `filter_once[0]` is `0` but `filter_iter[0]` is 0.999...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure if this is right; this is my first time working in this area of SciPy, but I think this is not working because of the different initial conditions of `lfilter()` vs `lfilter_zi()`.

The docs for `lfilter_zi()` say

> Construct initial conditions for lfilter for step response steady-state.

i.e. assume that a large step in the input has just occurred.

The docs for `lfilter()` say

> If zi is None or is not given then initial rest is assumed. See lfiltic for more information.

Reading the documentation for `lfiltic()`, you can construct a filter state which assumes initial rest like so:

```
z = scipy.signal.lfiltic(b, a, 0)
```

This `z` value causes your iterative solution to exactly match your all at once solution.

Inspecting `z`, it is just zeros, so you can simplify this to:

```
z = np.zeros(3)
```

I can't comment on whether you should use a step response initial state or a rest initial state, but this causes the the two solutions to give the same output.

Comment: Replacing `lfiltic_zi` by `lfiltic` worked like a charm. I don't understand what 'assume that a large step in the input has just occurred' actually means, but you fixed it. Thanks a lot.